# why can't i change base address of array in java while passing it as parameter?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I have written some code to find the first index of an element in an array in java but it's not working because arr+1 is not working. Can someone explain why I can't change the base address of the array in java?

```
public static int firstIndex(int[] arr, int n , int key ){
        if(n==0){
            return -1;
        }
        if(arr[0] == key)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            int fi  = firstIndex(**arr+1**,n-1,key);
            if(fi==-1){
                return -1;
            }
            else return fi+1;
        }
```

Comment: Java is not C++. Pointer calculations are not part of the language

Answer (score 2):

Java arrays are not C arrays.

In C an array is (effectively, basically, but not quite exactly) a pointer to the element type and it's up to the code itself to communicate and implements the constraints (such as element type, array size, ...).

In Java an array is a first-class citizen: it has a specific type and knows what its own length is.

This also means that C-style "tricks" like just pointing to the second element of an array and treating that thing as an array itself won't work.

For your specific case you can simply pass the start-index in addition to the array like this:

```
public static int firstIndex(int[] arr, int start, int n, int key) {
    if(n==0) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (arr[start] == key) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        int fi = firstIndex(arr, start+1, n-1, key);
        if (fi == -1) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return fi+1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: “In Java an array is a first-class citizen: it has a specific type and knows what its own length is.” — The same is true in C. The salient difference is that in C arrays can’t be passed as arguments. In a parameter list, `T[]` is *not* an array type but actually an alias for `T*`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: My C days are clearly too far behind by this point, feel free to edit my question to be more technically accurate.